# How to identify newsletter platform, through x-headers?

Tags: email

I am looking for a way to identify which newsletter platform is used, for newsletters I am receiving.

So far I am able to see it through gmail's `show original` which will indicate, for the most part, which platform was used, such as:

```
From:   ArtReview <emedia@artreview.com>Using MailChimp Mailer
From:   artnet Auctions <newsletter@artnet.com>Using sailthru.com
```

Unfortunately, this does not work all the time, when providers such as mandrillapp.com or mailgun.com are used.

**My question is:** is there a "surefire" way of identifying such platforms, either by querying mandatory x-headers or similar ?

Any input or feedback is much appreciated.

*ps* - I was not sure which stack forum to ask this question in, so if you find it belongs somewhere else then please let me know and I'll move it.

Comment: There is no way to identify mailing platforms unless they add some specific information themselves to the mails. This is not required in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct general way to identify any newsletter platform. It isn't that simple even with simple email from person to person. While some *mail user agents* (MUA) includes [`X-Mailer`](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-a-x-mailer-header) header,

> you may not be able to find the `X-Mailer` line. Continuing with the
> Gmail example, you will only be shown an `X-Mailer` line if the email in
> question was sent using an actual email program on the sender's
> computer. As webmail clients are becoming increasingly common,
> `X-Mailer` headers are actually becoming less common.

There might be some hints of the platform used, but not anything you could easily automate:

- Some platforms like to advertise themselves in the content rather than headers.
  You may find something like "*Powered by MyFancyNewsletterPlatform*" on the footer. Headers aren't so good for advertising purpose as usually they won't get read by actual humans.
- If the platform is hosted (instead of being an installed software), the originating server on `Received` headers may reveal the platform used.
- Order of the headers and how they are structured. Of course there's no direct signal of the name of the platform, but every MUA, webmail and newsletter platform has it's "signature" in how the headers are arranged and formed. While there's only a limited amount of [mandatory headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6) every mail should have, there's plenty of possible headers, and the order of the headers isn't fixed.

However, this would involve much of studying and comparing of newsletter headers from known sources. Maybe someone has been productive enough to create such sophisticated patterns for recognizing different platforms, but as new custom newsletter software are born all the time, investigating them would be endless work – and there would not be much of a real benefit.

Comment: Hi @esajokinen, thank you very much for the elaborating answer and as you point out it's very flaky to get a 100% correct answer. 

From what I can gather there is only a handful of platforms used in the segment I am looking at so I might be able to manually find patterns I can check against for now.